# JSpinner value change listener

Tags: java, swing, jspinner, changelistener

I have a `JSpinner` with `ChangeListener` directed. But the `ChangeListener` is only activated when I press enter or click on one of the `JSpinner` buttons. I would like to know how to enable `ChangeListener` when the value is changed.

Comment: Technically, that is what happening. Do you mean you want to know when the user toes something?

Comment: Yes.. I want to know when the user change the default value of the Jspinner

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a listener to the editor to be notified of any change:

```
JSpinner.DefaultEditor editor = (JSpinner.DefaultEditor)spinner.getEditor();
JTextField textField = editor.getTextField();
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener( ... );
```